# Initialize a batch-dependent variable in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow code that runs well and accurately, but occupies a lot of memory. Specifically, in my code, I have a for-loop that looks something like this:

```
K = 10
myarray1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,5,5]) # shape = [None, 5, 5]
myarray2 = tf.Variable( np.zeros([K,5,5]), dtype=tf.float32 )
vals = []
for k in range(0,K):
    tmp = tf.reduce_sum(myarray1*myarray2[k],axis=(1,2))
    vals.append(tmp)

result = tf.min( tf.stack(vals,axis=-1), axis=-1 )
```

Unfortunately, that takes a lot of memory as K gets to be big in my application. So, I want to have a better way of doing it. For example, in numpy/python, you would just keep track of the minimum value as you iterate through the loops, and update it on each iteration. It seems like I could use tf.assign, as:

```
K = 10
myarray1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,5,5]) # shape = [None, 5, 5]
myarray2 = tf.Variable( np.zeros([K,5,5]), dtype=tf.float32 )
min_value = tf.Variable(myarray1, validate_shape=False, trainable=False)
for k in range(0,K):
    tmp = myarray1*myarray2[k]
    idx = tf.where(tmp<min_value)
    tf.scatter_nd_assign(min_value, idx, tmp[idx], use_locking=True)

result = min_value
```

While this code builds the graph (when validate_shape=False), it fails to run because it complains that min_value has not been initialized. The issue is, when I run the initializer as:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

or

```
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.trainable_variables()))
```

it complains that I am not feeding in a placeholder. This actually makes sense because the definition of min_value depends on myarray1 in the graph.

What I would actually want to do is define a dummy variable that *doesn't* depend on myarray1's values, but does match its shape. I would like these values to be initialized as some number (in this case something large is fine), as I will manually ensure these are overwritten in the network.

Note: as far as I know, currently you cannot define a variable with an unknown shape unless you feed in another variable of the desired shape and set validate_shape=False). Maybe there is another way?

Any help / suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if don't know how to feed placeholder, read the tutorial.

```
K = 10
myarray1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,5,5]) # shape = [None, 5, 5]

###################ADD THIS ####################
sess=tf.Session()
FOO = tf.run(myarray1,feed_dict={myarray1: YOURDATA}) #get myarray1 value
#replace all myarray1 below with FOO
################################################

myarray2 = tf.Variable( np.zeros([K,5,5]), dtype=tf.float32 )
min_value = tf.Variable(FOO, validate_shape=False, trainable=False)
for k in range(0,K):
    tmp = FOO*myarray2[k]
    idx = tf.where(tmp<min_value)
    tf.scatter_nd_assign(min_value, idx, tmp[idx], use_locking=True)

result = min_value
```

### -------above new 15.April.2018------

Since I don't know your input data, I would like to try to make some steps.

Step_1: make a place for input data

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2])
```

Step_2: Get batches of data

```
batch_x=[[1,2],[3,4]]   #example
#since x=[None,2], the batch size would be batch_x_size/x_size=2
```

Step_3: make a session

```
sess=tf.Session()
```

---

if you have variables add the following code to initialize before calculation

```
init=tf.gobal_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

---

Step_4:

```
yourplaceholderdictiornay={x: batch_x}
sess.run(x, feed_dict=yourplaceholderdictiornay)
```

always feed your placeholder so it gets the value to calculate.

There is a [Tensorflow and Deep Learning without a PHD](https://gotocon.com/dl/goto-london-2016/slides/MartinGorner_TensorflowAndDeepLearningWithoutAPhD.pdf), very helpful PDF file, you can also find it on youtube with this title.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my problem carefully. The issue is that the min_value variable can't be initialized until the shape of myarray1 is known. Hence, "batch-dependent" variable. myarray1 can change on each run of the network, so there's no way to hard-code this.

Comment: Haha. I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, I don't think this answers the question. I could of course hard-code the value and shape of min_value. But that is not very useful if I want to change the batch-size at run-time. I guess my question was asking if there was a better way, as I haven't been able to find anything else online.